# create jquery cookies and store with multiple values

Tags: jquery

I have a script below that store a div (#account-list) value in cookies. If I wanted to store another value, let say #prepaid, how would I do that?

```
  <script>                                                                    
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      var selectedVal = jQuery.cookie("selected-add-order");
      if (selectedVal) {
        jQuery("#account-list").val(selectedVal);
      }
      jQuery("#account-list").on("change", function(){
        var selection = jQuery(this).val();
        jQuery.cookie("selected-add-order", selection, {expires: 365, path: '/'})
      });
    });
  </script>
```

Update:

```
        <div class="two-row">
          <div class="top-row">
            <div class="field-wrap">
              <label class="has-float-label">
                <input id="account-list" class="form-control" name="total_fee"/>
                <span>Total Fee</span>
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="field-wrap">
              <label class="has-float-label">
                <input id="prepaid" class="form-control" name="prepaid"/>
                <span>Prepaid Amount</span>
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Please an example of how you want it

Comment: Hi, I just updated my question. To be brief, I just want to store another value from another div. The code I have right now only stores one value, but I want to modify it and store another div value.

Comment: `account-list").on("change"` and `prepaid").on("change"`...or just a change

Comment: Thanks. But I also need the code to retrieve the value from the cookies for the prepaid div. How would I change  this statement->var selectedVal = jQuery.cookie("selected-add-order");
      if (selectedVal) {
        jQuery("#account-list").val(selectedVal);
      }

Comment: @ubuntujavy did you try my example below?

Comment: @RakeshGupta It doesn't work Rakesh.

Comment: @ubuntujavy Please try this updated plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/ImYC9P23YKaz6HLUVxc6?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may create your data object and stringify using JSON.stringify before storing in a cookie.

To retrieve the individual values, JSON.parse the data as under:

```
var selectedVal = JSON.parse($.cookie("selected-add-order"));
  console.log(selectedVal);
  if (selectedVal) {
    $("#account-list").val(selectedVal.account_list);
    $("#prepaid").val(selectedVal.prepaid);
  }

  $(".followChange").on("change", function() {
    $("#output").append(this.id + " changed <br>");
    var selection = {
      "account_list": $('#account-list').val(),
      "prepaid": $('#prepaid').val()
    };
    $.cookie("selected-add-order", JSON.stringify(selection), {
      expires: 365,
      path: '/'
    })
  });
```

Working example: https://plnkr.co/edit/ImYC9P23YKaz6HLUVxc6?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

[JSON.stringify() and JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/json#Using_native_JSON) to serialize/deserialize your data object

```
  //Then to get it from the cookie:
  var selectedVal = JSON.parse(jQuery.cookie("selected-add-order")) || {};
  if (selectedVal.al) {
    jQuery("#account-list").val(selectedVal.al);
  }
  if (selectedVal.prepaid) {
    jQuery("#account-list").val(selectedVal.prepaid);
  }
  jQuery("#account-list").on("change", function(){
    selectedVal["al"] = jQuery(this).val();
    //You can serialize the data as JSON, like this:
    $.cookie("selected-add-order",JSON.stringify(selectedVal),{expires:365, path:'/'})
  });
  jQuery("#prepaid").on("change", function(){
    selectedVal["prepaid"] = jQuery(this).val();
    $.cookie("selected-add-order",JSON.stringify(selectedVal),{expires:365, path:'/'})
  });
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. This code also doesn't retrieve the value from cookie for account-list either whereas the code I had before did.